# Mysql 5.5 recursive select id on parent_id

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица навигации

```
navigations
   id
   parent_id
   name
```

Таблица связана cсобой по navigations.parent_id on navigations.id

Как написать запрос который рекурсивно будет искать `name` в нем или в его родителях ?

Допустим моя таблица состоит из следующих колонок со значениями :

```
id         parent_id       name
1          0               aaa
2          1               bbb
3          2               ccc
```

значение колонки `name` уникальна,не повторяется.

Надо найти `name = 'aaa'` где id = 3, если не найдёт то продолжить искать в его родителе `(id = 2)`, и так далее пока не доберётся до id = 1 где `name= 'aaa'`
потомучто `id=3` находится в его родительской цепочке

Нужен Запрос на уровне sql.

вот мой код.Но он не работает так как мне надо :

```
SELECT 
  `pn`.`id` AS `parent_id` 
FROM
  `navigations` `pn` 
  INNER JOIN `navigations` `ch_n` 
    ON `ch_n`.`parent_id` = `pn`.`id` 
WHERE `ch_n`.`name` = 'aaa'
```

С помощью этого запроса на уровне PHP я могу его реализовать ,но нужно именно на уровне запроса.получить уже готовый результат.

Возможно ли это ?

Благодарю за помощь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mysql не умеет рекурсивные запросы, одним запросом невозможно. Через джойны можно выкрутиться если вы точно знаете уровень вложенности текущего элемента от корня.

Можно реализовать на хранимых процедурах. Для примера кода - https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/7161

Comment: Да в принципе я уже понял ,но все таки надеялся что будет :) .Спасибо за ссылку